# Ruby string/array combinations preserving order

Tags: ruby

I want to find all the combinations of a string preserving the order . Is there any built in method in Ruby to achieve this?

For example, `"abcd".all_combinations` should give the output:

```
a
b
c
d
ab
bc
cd
abc
bcd
abcd
```

Comment: Does it have to be a built-in method?

Comment: Any kind of implementation would work. But hoping there would be some method similar to object.combination

Comment: Have a look at http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/combination

Comment: These are [substrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring), not [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the ideal implementation, but this works:

```
def combinations(str)
  items = str.chars
  (1..items.length).map { |i| items.each_cons(i).map(&:join) }.flatten
end
```

Also check [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons). You can also just add it to the String class like this:

```
class String
  def combinations
    items = self.chars
    (1..items.length).map { |i| items.each_cons(i).map(&:join) }.flatten
  end
end

'abcd'.combinations
```

What is happening:

- We make the string an actual array of characters with [`String#chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chars).
- Then for each number `i` between 1 to the length of the string:

  - Call [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) which basically returns the possible combinations of the length `i` as an array of characters too. So if `i` is 2, then the result of `items.each_cons(2)` will be `[ ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'] ]`
  - The `.map(&:join)` part is basically calling [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) on each of the elements of that array of arrays, so it becomes `['ab', 'bc', 'cd']`
- The result of `(1..items.length).map { |i| items.each_cons(i).map(&:join) }` is: `[ ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['ab', 'bc', 'cd'], ['abc', 'bcd'], ['abcd'] ]` which is an array of arrays. We call [`Array#flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) on it to make it a simple array (read the flatten link for more).

Comment: That worked, Thanks a lot!. I am new to Ruby...Can you please explain us the implementation.

Comment: @maddy updated, hope that helps. You need to read the descriptions of the linked methods to get a better idea on what's happening.

Comment: @TamerShlash : Instead of `Enumberable#each_cons` you can use `Array#combination` also

Comment: @GaganGami "The implementation makes no guarantees about the order in which the combinations are yielded." does not work with the requirement "preserving the order".

Comment: `.map { ... }.flatten` → `.flat_map { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin function that does exactly what you're looking for.

String#each_cons looks interesting as Tamer points out.

Here's an alternate solution:

```
def all_combos(str)
  1.upto(str.length) do |segment_length|
    0.upto(str.length - segment_length) do |starting_point|
      puts str[starting_point, segment_length]
    end
  end
end

all_combos("abcd")
```

Comment: Very clean solution. Although I'd `yield` each substring instead of printing it, so you can call it via `all_combos('abcd') { |s| puts s }`.

Answer (score 1):

The starting and ending indices of the sub-strings form a pattern of a *combination with repetition*, for which Ruby does have a built-in method.

```
class String
  def all_combinations
    idx = (0 ... self.size).to_a
    idx.repeated_combination(2){|i,j| yield self[i..j]}
  end
end

"abcd".all_combinations{|combo| puts combo}
```

Comment: `each_combination` might be a better name.